# Missing Token Contract Address

Tags: solidity, remix

Two months ago, I wrote solidity contracts on remix.ethereum.org. They compiled and ran fine.

This code, which you can see here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b5c669c09683f285d44c36ab40555dd , has multiple contracts.  Two of which are:

- TestToken
- TestSale

In TestSale, there is a line that is:

```
TestToken public token = new TestToken();
```

When I created TestSale two months ago, remix will show TestSale's address and TestToken's address.  Now, remix's interface has changed and I do not see TestToken's address.  How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the contract with Javascript VM, it does not show the address of the token contract.

When you create the contract with Injected Web3 (with connection to Ropsten or Main net via MetaMask), then it shows the address of the token contract, as well as the address of the sale contract.